# Excel transform table pivot no aggregate

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, excel-2010

I have the following source table in Excel 2010

```
id param value
1  age   20
1  sex   M
2  age   30
2  sex   F
2  hght  185
```

I need to transform it into

```
id age sex hght
1  20  M
2  30  F   185
```

How can i do this in Excel 2010?
Parameters quantity could vary. 
The task looks very common but i didn't managed to get it using pivot or other Excel tools.

Comment: Do you want to automate this or just create a pivot?  What have you tried? I would just create something and move fields around. Hint: ID = Row label, Param is Column Label.  Are you trying to something more complex?

Comment: @SammyB, I think that the issue with using a pivot table is displaying M/F in the sex field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, however it is not completely automatic:

- Manually label your column headings (ID, age, sex, hght) in E1:H1 as per your example.
- Populate E2 with
  `=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(ROWS(E$1:E1),A$2:A$6,0)),"")`,press `Enter` and copy
  down.
- Populate F2 with
  `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$6,MATCH(1,($A$2:$A$6=$E2)*($B$2:$B$6=F$1),0)),"")`,
  concurrently press `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` and then copy down and
  across.

Your result should look like this:

[image]